# Should static IPs be set on the DNS/DHCP server, the host, or both?

Tags: ip, dhcp, dns, best-practices

Assuming a pretty regular business setup, when assigning static IPs for servers to use, should they be assigned on the DNS/DHCP server? Should they be configured individually on the hosts? Or should both be employed?

Following your answer to that, please explain why, and what (if any) cases there may be to *not* follow that method?

Comment: Either way is valid. You are going to get a lot of opinions on this question -- Sadly, that makes this question off-topic here.  It's a fine question to ask on [chat] (https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11177/general-network-engineering-recommendations), however.

Comment: @RonTrunk Fair enough, I had no idea it was such a debatable topic!